# Android Progress Dialog isnt in the center but bottom

Tags: java, android, progressdialog, progress, gravity

I've searched everywhere, and nothing found!
I need to set the position of my progressDialog in the center horizontal and vertical.
But when i compile my code by command line (i dont use eclipse) an error message is shown:
"cannot find symbol > Gravity..".
I think its a problem in the inclusion, i've imported looot of useless file 'cause i dont know what to import.
Somebody could help me?
Here is the code:

```
package com.worfut.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.view.KeyEvent; 
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo; 
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.view.Window;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


WebView WorfutWeb;
ProgressDialog progressBar;
private int progressBarStatus = 0;
private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
return true;
}



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
                 final Activity activity = this;

    WorfutWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

    WorfutWeb.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    WorfutWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    WorfutWeb.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    WorfutWeb.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    WorfutWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // prepare for a progress bar dialog
        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(this, R.id.mainWebView);
        progressBar.setCancelable(true);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressBar.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        progressBar.setMessage("Caricamento in corso..");
        progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.show();                                                

        WorfutWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, final int progress)
            {
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);

                if(progress == 100)
                {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }

            }
        });
    WorfutWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
   String html1 = "<html><body><br>";
   String html2 = "<div style='background: #007ac1; border: 2px solid lightblue; border-radius: 8px; padding: 4px;'>";
   String html3 = "<p style='font-weight: bolder;color: white;'><h2><u>Si &egrave; verificato un errore!</u></h3><br>";
   String html4 = "Possibili cause:<br><ul><li>";
   String html5 = "Non si dispone di una connessione Internet;</li><ul><li>Chiudere l'applicazione</li><li>Attivare la connessione Internet</li><li>Riavviare l'applicazione</li></ul><li>L'applicazione non risponde<ul><li>Chiudere e riaprire l'applicazione</li><li>Scriveteci sul Market Android</li></ul>";
   String html6 = "</li></ul></p><br><p align=right><font color=white><em>Worfut Staff.</em>&nbsp;</font></p></div></body></html>";
   String mime = "text/html";
   String encoding = "utf-8";
   view.loadData(html1+html2+html3+html4+html5+html6, mime, encoding);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
    WorfutWeb.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
    WorfutWeb.loadUrl("http://www.americantrip.altervista.org/try");


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_about:
WorfutWeb.loadUrl("http://americantrip.altervista.org/try/info.php"); 
// inside the menu button you don't need to call Super.loadUrl, LoadUrl its enough 
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_help:
WorfutWeb.loadUrl("http://americantrip.altervista.org/try/help.php"); 
// inside the menu button you don't need to call Super.loadUrl, LoadUrl its enough 
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_search:
WorfutWeb.loadUrl("http://americantrip.altervista.org/try/cerca.php"); 
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_exit:
       finish();
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void onResume() {  
   super.onResume();  
   if (WorfutWeb != null) {  
    WorfutWeb.resumeTimers();  
   }  
 }  

public void onPause() {  
   super.onPause();  
   if (WorfutWeb != null) {  
    WorfutWeb.pauseTimers();  
   }  
 }  


public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.dismiss();
    }
}

 // To handle "Back" kewy press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && WorfutWeb.canGoBack()) {
        WorfutWeb.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

This is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/sfondo" 
    android:gravity="center"> 
    > 
    <WebView android:id="@+id/mainWebView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1" /> 
 </LinearLayout>
```

The part with the error is this:

```
    progressBar.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

and i think its correct, but maybe i have to import something else.
Thanks yall.

P.S. i've already seen http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setGravity(int)
and i've took from there the "import android.widget.LinearLayout". seems to be the same, dont run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import android.view.Gravity;
```

Comment: Yessss!!!! Thankssss! ps. could i ask you where i can LEARN what to import? :> developer.android.com doesnt write what to import!

Comment: its all right, no error, but the progress dialog is still bottom and not center ! :(((

Comment: I was actually going to ask that why don't you use eclipse? You don't need to worry about any imports whatsoever. You can use your time for concentrating on the logic or design.

Comment: im downloading it now... however it doesnt show it in the center :(

Comment: In the layout file, your webview is inside what kind of layout( Linear or Relative) ?

Comment: Linear my webview is into the linear

Comment: It should be fine. However, I might be able to help you more if you post your layout file as well.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sfondo"
    android:gravity="center">
     >
    <WebView
      android:id="@+id/mainWebView"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/sfondo" 
    > 
    > 
    <WebView android:id="@+id/mainWebView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
         /> 
 </LinearLayout>
```

modified your layout, i guess the progress wont be at the center as you declared your layout on the center. anyway if that doesn't help you. 
the easiest way to do it is.

```
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams para=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
                para.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                progressBar.setLayoutParams(para);
```

and it should work. if that fixed your issue please do accept the answer so others can get use of it. cheers

Comment: _`-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /.classes
    [javac] /.../MainActivity.java:32: android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams is already defined in a single-type import
    [javac] import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] /../MainActivity.java:76: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method setLayoutParams(android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams)
    [javac] location: class android.app.ProgressDialog
    [javac]             progressBar.setLayoutParams(para);
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] 2 errors
`_

Comment: gimme an error your edit. (only with the layout edit dont run)

Comment: you have to import FrameLayout Pramas not other layoutparams

Comment: The method setLayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams) is undefined for the type ProgressDialog

Comment: it doesnt accept "_progressBar.setLayoutParams(para);_" and Eclipse suggest me to "add cast to progressBar" but what i have to do? 'cause if i click on "add cast..." the row change to "_((WebView) progressBar).setLayoutParams(para);_" and now the error is "cannot cast from ProgressDialog to WebView". THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!